# Create tab for related content types

Tags: views

How do I link 2 content types (business, photo) together and able to display as a tab? is there a module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple way (i.e., without coding) would be to use Panels module, and create a node type view page override for the first content type.  Then use a nodereference field to make the first content type reference a node of the second type.  Lastly, use Panels' context system to generate a new context of that referenced node, and display it in whatever means you want on the overridden node view page.

Comment: Can you elaborate, because i am not sure I understand. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs might fit your bill